# Huge chunks of the video are misarranged or missing in the render, but they're fine in the preview. (when using Blender for video editing)

Tags: rendering

Things that show up as being trimmed properly in the preview aren't doing that in the renderer. I am starting to wonder if it's showing an outdated version of my video, because I did have something similar to this before I had finished editing.

I've read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147337/really-low-fps-in-the-preview-window-of-the-video-editor), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152881/video-render-is-splitting-the-final-video-into-chunks?newreg=12f0194e888941268ec940b907e0f7a8), [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/not-rendering-full-video/528211), etc., but none of them have solved my problem.

I've set my FPS at 24 FPS. I've saved the project, closed Blender, and re-opened the project multiple times.

I have been Googling both very detailed descriptions of my questions (like what I put as my title) as well as things like "how to fix Blender's rendering".

This has been happening to me for a while. The last time it happened, I just let it happen and lost a bit of my video because I didn't have the time to deal with it, but this time, my video is basically unintelligible, so I can't really just roll with it anymore.

I'm really sorry if this seems vague as hell. I'm also confused about what the program is doing. It's hard to describe.

Comment: hi, could you please add some screenshots?                      how to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Upload your file here :  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi. As it stands this question is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, edit your current post.

Comment: @Ribbit12 It isn't letting me upload a file to the blend-exchange site. It's at the 0% progress of the loading bar and is stuck there. I checked the DevTools console, and there's one error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()" on /api/users/current:1